# Does Windows optimise differently for SSD installation?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have two solid state hard drives in two different laptops, a Samsung 840 Pro 256GB and a Crucial MX100 512GB. I got the Samsung first and in that machine it absolutely flies, with a Windows rating off the chart 7.9. The newer Crucial by all benchmark reviews is faster than the Samsung, and is in a higher end laptop. However its performance is only slightly better than the HDD that came out of it with a Windows rating of 7.7. The Crucial also makes some very HDD type noises. I know solid state devices can make noise, this just seems excessive.

The only difference seems to be that for the Samsung, I installed Windows freshly onto it and the Crucial, I made efforts to duplicate the system's existing partitions and existing Windows installation which was successful. The only thing I can think is that Windows installs itself in some way optimised for the type of drive it is running on and doing a partition copy like that brings Windows in optimised for a mechanical drive.

Which is true/more likely:
a) The drive is faulty,
b) Windows self-optimises, or
c) other.

If other, what?

**Edit:**
Benchmark result as requested:

[image]

These results are well short of even the worst performances on  the [UserBenchmark](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/10775/Crucial-CT512MX100SSD1) site.

Comment: post pictures of AS SSD Benchmark for your Crucial: http://alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have added the benchmark, it does look low compared to what I've seen.

Comment: It's not low..;

Comment: You have not specified how you replicated your old hdd but you may need to realign your partitions to get optimal performance, see eg. here http://us.hardware.info/reviews/4583/how-to-copy-hdd-to-ssd-with-correct-4k-alignment (page 3 onward)

Comment: I used a Ubuntu live CD to duplicate the partition structure, and then copied the Windows partitions across. That didn't immediately work, I needed to run a chkdsk on it which cleaned up more things than I was expecting. After that Windows booted fine. I'm tempted to reinstall Windows just as an experiment though.

Comment: check your partition alignment, here is a gparted method of properly aligning when cloning (iirc I used it myself when when I ported my Windows install and it worked very well) - I can't say if it will hep with performance of your install but it's worth a try. Oh yes, link here: http://lifehacker.com/5837769/make-sure-your-partitions-are-correctly-aligned-for-optimal-solid-state-drive-performance

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot to mention, just did the check using 'wmic partition get Name, StartingOffset', all the start points are divisible by 4096 so it's not that. Sound idea though.

Comment: this looks like you only have SATA2 not SATA3. Which Laptop do you use?

Comment: It's an HP Elitebook, looking at the spec I think you're right, 3Gb/s SATA II... Is that really all I can expect then from the drive and nothing is particularly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the laptop only provides SATA II with 3Gb/s, the values you see in AS SSD Benchmark are fine. You can't improve this.